# Formula to return result from next sheet if first sheet doesn't return match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in `Sheet6` to look up a value from `Sheet5` and return it, but sometimes, if values are not in `Sheet5`, I want it to check in `Sheet7`.

`Sheet6` and `Sheet7` have same pattern in all column, only columns have different values.

How can I rewrite the formula in `Sheet 6` in order to check data in `sheet 5` first and if data were not found, then `Sheet7` will be automatically matched?

**Original formula in `Sheet 6`:**

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Sheet5!$A$4:$AG$30,MATCH($C$25,Sheet5!G4:G30,0),2)),"",INDEX(Sheet5!$A$4:$AG$30,MATCH($C$25, Sheet5!G4:G30,0),2))
```

---

*Edit: Screenshots below to clarify my question*
[image: Sheet 5]

[image: Sheet 6]

[image: Sheet 7]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple references to `Sheet5` so without knowing what your data looks like, or more what you're trying to, it's tough to say for sure, but perhaps you need something like this:

`=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Sheet5!$A$4:$AG$30,MATCH($C$25,Sheet5!G4:G30,0),2)),INDEX(Sheet7!$A$4:$AG$30,MATCH($C$25,Sheet7!G4:G30,0),2),INDEX(Sheet5!$A$4:$AG$30,MATCH($C$25,Sheet5!G4:G30,0),2))`

...so where it would before return `''` if "`NA`", it will now return the matching formula but using `Sheet7` instead of `Sheet5`.

Comment: ...also, just so you're aware, this isn't normally the type of question that should be asked here... it's not an "emergency fix-it service", see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site as well as "[ask]".  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
=iferror(iferror(index(Sheet5!$B$4:$B$30, MATCH($C$25, Sheet5!G4:G30, 0)), 
                 index(Sheet6!$B$4:$B$30, MATCH($C$25, Sheet6!G4:G30, 0))), text(,))
```

If C25 not found in Sheet5!G4:G30, look in Sheet6!G4:G30. If not found in either then `""`.